# PHP calculator increase

Tags: php

I am creating simple calculator. I am just learning php and this is a small project.I have created a calculator with two inputs but I am now testing it with just one. It works but only if you type number+number. It doesn't work if it is number+number+number.

I would like that it would work if you inputted 2+2+2... or 2*2*2... or 6-2-2... and 2/2/2...

Code:

```
// Create Variables
$y = $_POST["input1"];

// Echo input value on screen
echo "<p>Operation: " . $y . "</p>";

// Validation
if(empty($y)){
  ?>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#error').append('Error: Your Input is empty');
      });
    </script>
  <?php
}elseif(preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/", $y)){
  ?>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#error').append('Error: You can only input numbers');
      });
    </script>
  <?php
}else{

  // Calculation Brain FOR + Operator
  if (strpos($y,'+') !== false) {
    $omega = substr($y, 0, strpos($y, '+'));
    $alpha = substr($y, strpos($y, '+') + 1);

    echo "<p>Omega: " . $omega . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Alpha: " . $alpha . "</p>";

    $gamma = $omega + $alpha;
    // The Sum FOR + operator
    echo "Calculation: " . $gamma;
  }
}
```

Comment: explode your string into an array take the delimiter and loop through the array with + - * /.

Comment: check `eval()` function. this comment may be helpful http://www.php.net/eval#107377

Answer (score 0):

That's usually a bad practice, but here you can use eval. But you have first to check that your string doesn't contains disallowed characters.

```
$allowedCharacters = "0123456789./*-+()% ";
if(preg_match('/^[^'.preg_quote($allowedCharacters).']+$/'), $y) {
    eval('$result = '.$y.';');
    echo "Calculation: " . $result;
}
```

The only problem is that you'll not be able to handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this for the same operation

```
$test='2+2*3';
eval('$calc = '.$test.';');
echo "Calculation: " . $calc;
```

the out should be : 8